# "[TTM] Buffer eviction failed" loop

Tags: login

I had locked my ubuntu desktop, then came back 40 minutes later and the lock screen time was stuck at 30 minutes ago. Nothing happened when I pressed enter or tried to get to the login screen, but I could move my mouse around, so I tried Ctrl-Alt-F3 to see if anything happened. I didn't type in any commands, but the terminal outputed:

```
linux login: [447864.849129] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
[447864.849145] nouveau 000:01:00.0: systemmd-logind[1077]: fail ttm_validate
[447864.849153] nouveau 000:01:00.0: systemmd-logind[1077]: validating bo list
[447864.849161] nouveau 000:01:00.0: systemmd-logind[1077]: validate -1
[447895.056421] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
[447925.263809] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
[447955.471490] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
[447985.678829] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
[447915.886441] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
```

...
And it seemed to be stuck in this loop. I went back to the lock screen with Ctrl-Alt-F1 (and it took about a minute to do so), and the screen was still stuck even though I could move my mouse around. I can't press the power options button on the upper right either. I ended up force-shutting down my computer anyway, but is there anything I could have done to fix this?